# How to limit Eclipse's "References => Project" search to the project itself?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is one things that has bothered me since I started using Eclipse. If I'm in my project, and selects "References => Project", targeting, for example, this:

```
System.err.println()
```

from within one of my source code file, I expect to only see references to it (System.err.println()) in my project, and not, in the JDK, and the 1000 other jars my project depends on. The "Preferences" section for "Search" (General=>Search) is ludicrously small and useless. And even if I create a "Working Set", with just my project in it, it still does exactly the same thing. For some unique names, using text search in *.java does the trick, but often it's not any better.

So, I'd like to know if there is some magic setting I haven't found, that "fixes" the search, or alternatively, if there is some Eclipse Search Plugin out there, that actually gets this right.

It's not just a question of having to sort through much more useless results, but also that actually searching just within my project should be much faster, therefore saving time.

Comment: IMO creating a "working set" with just _srource content_ in it, is just a one time job, and given that they can be used across different views in Eclipse, its definitely worth creating them.

Comment: The window to create a working set allows me to choose a project, but there does not seem to be any "source content" switch that I can see anywhere, and selecting "edit" for a working set just allows me to change the selected project. How do I get to this "source content" flag for a working set?

Comment: Manually. You manually choose relevant source folders. _New working set -> Resource -> choose appropriate src folders only -> Finish_. Thats it.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't thinking that "source code" falls under "Resource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to see the references to System.err.println() in your project . if is it correct, So why you are not using the find references (press Ctrl + Alt + h on the method) .

Comment: So this is the "Search => Java" and then in "Search In", just keep "Sources" selected (I'm not good at remembering the keyboard shortcuts). That seems to do it. Thanks. I just wish this was the default behavior for the "References => Project".

Answer (score -1):

try to close other projects in the same work space

Comment: The problem is not that Eclipse searches in the other open projects, it doesn't. The problem is that it considers "dependencies" (including the JDK) as being part of the project, when it comes to search.